# Does being a student in the EU allow one to do internships anywhere in the EU?

Tags: european-union

Can a student, studying in the EU with a student visa take on a summer internship?  Could they take an internship anywhere in the EU?

I tried asking my student office but they haven't replied.

Comment: It dpeends on several factors, but likely not. It might matter if you receive a salary or compensation, if the internship is required by your degree or optional, and the length.

Comment: With your student visa, assuming it is from a Schengen country, you can go to another Schengen country for up to 90 days in any 180-day period, which should be enough for a summer internship, but whether you can work will depend on national law in the country where the internship is located.  Thus it's possible that some countries would require you to apply for and receive additional authorization in the form of a work permit while others might not.  I am not aware of EU law governing this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, as a non-EU/EEA/CH citizen, you don't benefit from the freedom of movement and work given to EU citizens by Union law.
Depending on the national law of the country you're doing your masters in, you may be able to do an internship in that country

If you wish to do an internship in other EU countries, you must follow the appropriate rules as a non-EU citizen in the country you wish to do one